# Preferred method for inline code samples

Tags: listings, minted, inline

I tend to use the `minted` package for including code samples within my documents, which produces very nice output. However, because Pygments always produces a verbatim *environment* there's no way to inline the code if I need to discuss particular features of it. What is the best way to typeset inline code to go alongside code produced by `minted`?

Using the `listings` package just for `\lstinline` is one option I've considered, but it seems a bit odd to use both `minted` and `listings` together. I've used `listings` in the past, but (in my opinion and with the samples I've tried) I don't think the output is as nice as that produced with `minted`. Are there any other means of producing inline code that I'm unaware of?

Comment: The output of `listings` can be configured quite a bit, see for example this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8230/what-configuration-do-you-propose-for-listings-sty-to-make-the-output-look-comf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `minted` if you are willing to patch it:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{ifplatform}
\ifwindows\else
\newcommand*{\TestAppExists}[1]{% there is no `which -s` on Linux
  \immediate\write18{which -- '#1' > /dev/null && touch -- '\jobname.aex'}%
  \IfFileExists{\jobname.aex}{%
    \AppExiststrue
    \DeleteFile{\jobname.aex}%
  }{%
    \AppExistsfalse
  }
}
\fi
\usepackage{minted}
\makeatletter
% avoid space tokens since we're in horizontal mode
\renewcommand\mint[3][]{%
  \DefineShortVerb{#3}%
  \minted@resetoptions
  \setkeys{minted@opt}{#1}%
  \SaveVerb[aftersave={%
    \UndefineShortVerb{#3}%
    \minted@savecode{\FV@SV@minted@verb}%
    \minted@pygmentize{#2}%
    \DeleteFile{\jobname.pyg}}]{minted@verb}#3}
\renewcommand\minted@savecode[1]{%
  \immediate\openout\minted@code\jobname.pyg\relax
  \immediate\write\minted@code{#1}%
  \immediate\closeout\minted@code}
\renewcommand\minted@pygmentize[2][\jobname.pyg]{%
  \def\minted@cmd{pygmentize -l #2 -f latex -F tokenmerge
    \minted@opt{gobble} \minted@opt{texcl} \minted@opt{mathescape}
    \minted@opt{linenos} -P "verboptions=\minted@opt{extra}"
    -o \jobname.out.pyg #1}%
  \immediate\write18{\minted@cmd}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@bgcolor}{}}%
   {}%
   {\begin{minted@colorbg}{\minted@opt@bgcolor}}%
  \input{\jobname.out.pyg}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@bgcolor}{}}%
   {}%
   {\end{minted@colorbg}}%
  \DeleteFile{\jobname.out.pyg}}
\makeatother
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}
\begin{document}
This is some inline code \mint{c++}|for i=1;i<20;i++| and more \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: This hack doesn't work anymore. It makes everything inline instead of just the \mint command.

Answer (score 7):

AFIK this is an area, where you cannot use Pygments.

The simplest way to achieve it from a "typing" point of view is to use a "short verbatim".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
\begin{document}
This is some inline code |for i=1;i<20;i++| and more \ldots
\end{document}
```

The package `fancyvrb` offers a number of customizations as well.

Comment: This loses me all of the syntax analysis offered by a package such as `listings` or `minted`. See [here](http://imgur.com/gUUo4) for a comparison between this suggestion and the accepted minted solution.

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, see also [issue 15](http://code.google.com/p/minted/issues/detail?id=15) on the minted project page, and in particular [a temporary fix](http://code.google.com/p/minted/issues/attachmentText?id=15&aid=3479164652891680731&name=minted.sty&token=52477211c465ea4f065e5558515861ac) that I posted there (but which probably does much the same as Philipp’s hack anyway).

In summary, this is on the “to do” list but not yet officially supported since I’m currently busy and don’t have time to work on minted.

Answer (score 0):

The `\mintinline` feature allows you to write inlined code with the `minted` package.