# How to have inline code and line numbering with minted?

Tags: minted, line-numbering, inline

I'm using the code found in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10884/17697) answer to allow `minted` to provide inline code. But, unfortunately, this breaks line numbering, which is not shown anymore.

How can I have both inline code *and* line numbering with `minted`?

---

MWE: no inline code with line numbering:

```
\documentclass[a6paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

Ciao \mint[linenos]{c}/int a = 1;/ Prova

\begin{minted}[linenos]{c}
    int a = 1;
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

MWE with inline code, line numbering not working:

```
\documentclass[a6paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
% avoid space tokens since we're in horizontal mode
\renewcommand\mint[3][]{%
  \DefineShortVerb{#3}%
  \minted@resetoptions
  \setkeys{minted@opt}{#1}%
  \SaveVerb[aftersave={%
    \UndefineShortVerb{#3}%
    \minted@savecode{\FV@SV@minted@verb}%
    \minted@pygmentize{#2}%
    \DeleteFile{\jobname.pyg}}]{minted@verb}#3}
\renewcommand\minted@savecode[1]{%
  \immediate\openout\minted@code\jobname.pyg\relax
  \immediate\write\minted@code{#1}%
  \immediate\closeout\minted@code}
\renewcommand\minted@pygmentize[2][\jobname.pyg]{%
  \def\minted@cmd{pygmentize -l #2 -f latex -F tokenmerge
    \minted@opt{gobble} \minted@opt{texcl} \minted@opt{mathescape}
    \minted@opt{linenos} -P "verboptions=\minted@opt{extra}"
    -o \jobname.out.pyg #1}%
  \immediate\write18{\minted@cmd}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@bgcolor}{}}%
   {}%
   {\begin{minted@colorbg}{\minted@opt@bgcolor}}%
  \input{\jobname.out.pyg}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@bgcolor}{}}%
   {}%
   {\end{minted@colorbg}}%
  \DeleteFile{\jobname.out.pyg}}
\makeatother
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}

\begin{document}

Ciao \mint[linenos]{c}/int a = 1;/ Prova

\begin{minted}[linenos]{c}
    int a = 1;
\end{minted}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Would a verbatim solution be good enough, or do you need the color highlighting that minted provides?  Also, how is inline code supposed to look, with line numbering?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'd like to have the syntax highlighting with inline code as well. The problem with line numbering is not with inline code: *all* line numbering is broken(as you can see in the last output).

Comment: Too bad.  I know how to do a few verbatim tricks, but don't know anythong about minted.  Good luck from another reader!

Answer (score 1):

Starting from version 2, `minted` supports `\mintinline`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

Ciao \mintinline{c}/int a = 1;/ Prova

\begin{minted}[linenos]{c}
    int a = 1;
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]