# beautiful listing for CSharp

Tags: listings, typography

Does anyone have a nice typesetting style for the C# language using `listings`? I configure it in this way:

```
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,,basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  showspaces=false,showtabs=false,,breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,breakatwhitespace=true,
  escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
```

But still it doesn't look fine, T_T. In my configuration I have characters that are too rounded and the code looks like if it was written using a typewriter. I don't want that. I want a modern, clear font, that looks more similar to the what I see in Visual Studio.

**Final Election.**

Thanks to all you guys, for give me ways to improve the appearance of the code. My final election is from the answer of @PauloCereda, little tuned with one of the comments and a bfseries touch for keywords. Here is the code and how it looks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
breakatwhitespace=true,
escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords}\bfseries,
stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The default Visual Studio font also is a typewriter style/monospace font :-)

Comment: @AndreyVihrov xD, perhaps that they look fine, not bloated or overly rounded. I also think that the space between characters is bigger than normal in listings.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the Visual Studio font name is `Consolas`. There's an alternative font called [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html), which is pretty good.

Comment: Additionally, you can find the free Microsoft fonts listed [here](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ClearTypeFonts.mspx)

Comment: See my answer [here (click)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193475/19356).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on Thorsten's code, I added colors to keywords, strings and comments and replaced the current typewriter font by `Inconsolata`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
  commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
  keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
  stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
/**
* Prints Hello World.
**/
class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image: Hello world.]

According to the `Inconsolata` documentation, loading it redefines the `\tt` font.

Comment: perhaps the colors looks cool, when i zoom in or zoom out the clarity of the font is lost.

Comment: forget my previous comment, i don't know how but now the fonts looks perfect. One more help please, i try to make the keywords bold but perhaps i put "keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords}\bfseries" it seems that it ignore the instruction.

Comment: @voodoomsr: Unfortunately, it seems that the `Inconsolata` font has no bold face. Maybe we can choose another typewriter font.

Comment: @voodoomsr: Take a look at [beramono](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/beramono/), which is a modern-looking (not too Courier-like) pretty good monotype font that includes bold face and slanted versions.

Comment: @Daniel ouuuuu yea with that font and the color configuration that @PauloCereda provide plus the bfseries for the keywords produce the clear and beautiful look that i want :D

Comment: How does writing `escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}` allow you to use multiple characters for the escape sequence? The manual only says that it takes two characters. Is this something universal to TeX?

Answer (score 4):

You may use `basicstyle` to customize the font:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could use `lmodern` instead of `bold-extra` as Andrey Vihrov suggested.

Comment: In an answer I was writing, I also used `\usepackage{lmodern}`. This loads a bold typewriter font which is used for identifiers.

Comment: they look a little better but they lost all the customization for special keywords, operators, etc, i.e. they are presented as plain text.

Comment: Err, I meant keywords.

Comment: @voodoomsr: Try the above command and see if it's better. Note that the bold typewriter font is only _slightly_ heavier than the regular one. There is a darker font, but IMO it looks worse.

Comment: @voodoomsr See my updated code

Comment: well it is a improvement but one thing remains....the space between characters, i look and look and look again and i'm almost sure that they have more than the normal space between

Comment: @voodoomsr I added `columns=fullflexible`

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of [Visual Studio styles](http://studiostyl.es/schemes) that you can choose as a reference. The following figure shows some of them.

[image]

Afterwards, you need to look up the name of colors, fonts, etc used there to create your own listings style. Creating listings style can be found in [What configuration do you propose for listings.sty to make the output look comfortable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8230/2099).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind solutions that involve other tools, I like to use [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) to generate code listings for inclusion in my documents.  It can process dozens of programming languages and other markup.  Just pipe your code listing through their command-line program and `\input` the resulting markup in your document.

Comment: Or, use the [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) package.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile the document with `xelatex` or `lualatex`, you can use any TrueType or OpenType font you want. So you could use for example the font that Visual Studio uses. Just load the `fontspec` package and use something like `\setmonofont{Inconsolata}` together with `basicstyle=\texttt`. Or define a font family explicitly for code, as in the following example.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec,xcolor}

% Define \codefont to switch to the font 'Ubuntu'.
% (I find the font size more pleasing when the lower case
% characters are scaled to the size of the lower case of the
% surrounding text.)
\newfontfamily\codefont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Ubuntu}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
  basicstyle=\codefont,             % use the font defined as \codefont
  stringstyle=\color{blue!70!black},
  commentstyle=\color{green!70!black},
  columns=fullflexible
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
// A program that prints a greeting message.
class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Also see the [listings manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for lots of ways to customize the formatting of listings.

Comment: Btw, the Ubuntu font is available from http://font.ubuntu.com/

Comment: i really like how this look, is it possible to put a working code with inconsolata?...i try what you say but i receive an error. Maybe i'm using bad the xelatex command, is the first time i use it, :D. i always use pdflatex.exe.

Comment: @voo: Did you install the font? It is hard to help you without the error message.

Comment: @Caramdir yes it is installed, here is the log of the error http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15811510/lol.log

Comment: @voo: It seems you are compiling the example with the Ubuntu font. If you do that you also need to install that font. If you want Inconsolata, try compiling the code I posted in the answer, but with `Ubuntu` replaced by `Inconsolata`. Also MikTeX 2.8 might have old versions of XeTeX and `fontspec`, which might cause problems.

Comment: @Caramdir I try with both fonts but the same error arise. What distribution do you recommend? Miktex 2.8 is the last version of Miktex so maybe a need to move on to other distribution

Comment: @voo: 2.9 is the latest (was released last October). I'll try later today compiling this on a Windows computer.

Comment: @Caramdir thanks, you are right i got confused because in "Recent News" in Miktex Homepage appears 2.9 as beta so i do not continue looking further, :D. I'm going to update my Miktex install and see what happend. I'm thinking that the problem comes from other thing, the version of xetex change very very little in 2.8 to 2.9 of Miktex, xetex 0.9995.1->xetex 0.9997.4

Comment: @voo: The code works fine with MikTeX 2.9.