# Is it possible to find methods in source code using \inputminted?

Tags: minted

My document MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\inputminted[gobble=4,firstnumber=3,firstline=3,lastline=9,linenos,tabsize=4]{java}{Foo.java}
\end{document}
```

Content of Foo.java:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Presented TeX document will show and format method `main`.
When I change the code of `Foo` class (e.g. add a new method above `main` or expand it), I would need to manually change the range of lines to show.
Can it somehow be done automatically? I think of comments as a markers in the java code. Something like in one of the examples below:

```
public class Foo
{
    //start-main
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    //end-main
}
```

or

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) //start-main
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    } //end-main
}
```

Is it possible to pass this to LaTeX (or Pygments in this case)?
I would like to be able to ignore those markers when presenting a larger portion of code (e.g. whole `Foo.java` file) but this is not as important as the main question. Maybe there is another way without any markers? For example telling Pygments to print `main` method from `Foo` class.
Of course I don't want to be limited to methods only. I want to be able to mark any part of the code this way.

Comment: I will use `listings` package instead.

Comment: @CounterTerrorist, does `listings` have this feature? I prefer `minted` beceuse of better looking output.

Comment: read my answer please.

Comment: @Ichibann: I agree that the **default** output of `minted` is somewhat more polished that the **default** output of `listings`; however, `listings` is pretty flexible wrt adapting the typesetting. If you search for the `listings` tag you will find a couple of "good looking" (well, it's a matter of taste...) examples (such as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18376/beautiful-listing-for-csharp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is taken from `listings` manual page 51 and 52.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is nice :). If there were something like this in `minted`...

Comment: This is not minted, but it works.