# How can I typeset LaTeX source code with this very specific syntax highlighting?

Tags: listings, highlighting

I want to put some LaTeX source code in my PDF output with the style like this:

[image]

Color in text mode is white, in math mode is yellow and in comments is grey. For control sequences, I divide it into four kinds with different highlight mode:

- Commands in text mode are cyan, and its argument(s) (non-optional) is/are orange and italic.
- Commands in text mode are cyan, but its argument(s) (non-optional) is/are white and upright.
- Commands in text mode are rose-color, and its optional argument(s) is/are orange and italic, non-optional argument(s) is/are cyan and italic.
- Commands in math mode are purple, its arguments (optional or non-optional) should be rose-color and upright.

Remember that backslash before a command is always highlighted with the same color of the command, but delimiters of arguments remains white (color of body text).

I tried and searched the web for about ten hours, but still failed. Any hints or clues would be appreciated.

Comment: `minted` is probably you best bet.

Comment: Might be of your interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102596/minted-vs-texments-vs-verbments

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8230/19356 might help.

Comment: @You Thank you for you comment, and sorry for my late, since my computer shut down for several days. I've read the documentation of `minted`, however, I couldn't compile a simple example provided by it. What's worse, I'm not familiar with Python, so.. Should I open another question for those problems?

Comment: @juliohm It seems that most people prefer Python-based packages, such as `minted`, or other script-based packages (am I right?). The reason, I guess, is that these script languages provide much more controlling and conditional switching than LaTeX itself does. I will follow your advice to study these packages when I get rid of my current article. :)

Comment: @DonutE.Knot Thank you for your kindly help! However, LaTeX code and the code displayed in the link you provided differ greatly. Since LaTeX put arguments in braces (`{}`), optional ones in square brackets (`[]`) and start a control sequence with a backslash (\\), situation goes much knottier.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot BTW, do you know how to mark a backslash as code in Markdown?

Comment: @TachibanaKanade Your specs are not self-consistent; in particular, your first two bullet points conflict. `listings` can do a lot, but nothing can be done without precise highlighting specifications.

Comment: @TachibanaKanade Install Python and Pygment and you will be able to use minted (note that Python package installations don't require any Python knowledge at all!). When that is completed, using `monokai` theme will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 4):

This solution isn't perfect (hence the community wiki), but it might get you or someone else started (if anyone would like to improve this solution, please feel free).

[image: screenshot]

I've borrowed some code from [Emphasize (color) contents between two delimiters in listings, but not the delimiters themselves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147836/emphasize-contents-between-two-with-listings) to help the grouping delimiters.

It's a tricky problem because you essentially wish to change the [`listings`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/listings) style midway through the `listings` (I tried a few things, but couldn't get it working).

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}           
\usepackage{xcolor}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147836/emphasize-contents-between-two-with-listings
\def\begindollar{\ttfamily\$\bgroup\color{yellow}\aftergroup\enddollar}
\def\enddollar{\$\egroup}

% tweaked from above for { }
\def\beginbrace{\ttfamily\color{white}{\{}\bgroup\color{orange}\itshape\aftergroup\endbrace}
\def\endbrace{\color{white}{\}}\egroup}

% tweaked from above for [ ]
\def\beginbracket{\ttfamily\color{white}{[}\bgroup\color{orange}\itshape\aftergroup\endbracket}
\def\endbracket{\color{white}{]}\egroup}
\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{orange},language={[LaTeX]TeX},   
    texcsstyle=*\color{cyan},
    columns=flexible,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black},
    commentstyle=\color{gray},    % comments
    literate={usepackage}{\bgroup\color{purple}{usepackage}\egroup}1
    {documentclass}{\bgroup\color{purple}{documentclass}\egroup}1,
    moredelim = **[is][\begindollar]{\$}{\$},
    moredelim=**[is][\beginbrace]{\{}{\}},
    moredelim=**[is][\beginbracket]{[}{]},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz \color{blue} $(a+b)$ $n \choose r$ % \tikz
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, this is a fantastic work! However, it has some foibles, such as the backslash signs were colored differ from the following control sequence, and command(s) in math environment does/do not color as a special part. I will read the documentation more carefully and try to improve this answer later. Again, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @TachibanaKanade yes indeed, it isn't perfect :) if you can improve it, please feel free!